# django-tables2 and LinkColumn. Correct path to Django-admin site page

Tags: django, django-admin, django-tables2

I am developing cmdb application and trying to create a link to admin page of the device ( /admin/cmdb/device/**device_id**/) in django-tables2 LinkColumn with the following syntax:

```
id = tables.LinkColumn('admin:cmdb:device', args=[A('pk')])
```

This fails with error

> NoReverseMatch at /cmdb/emp/171/
>
> 'cmdb' is not a registered namespace inside 'admin'

(/cmdb/emp/171/ - is the page on which the table is rendered)

How can I write the correct path in LinkColumn argument to Django admin page?

---

The goal could be achieved by using TemplateColumn:

```
id2 = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="/admin/cmdb/device/{{record.id}}">{{record.id}}</a>')
```

but possibly someone could advise how to use LinkColumn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not about the `LinkColumn` but about finding out the url names of the django admin pages.

In any case, you can find your answer here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls

So if the name of your application is `cmdb` and the name of your model is `device`, the url name of the device edit page would be `admin:cmdb_device_change` which could be used in the `LinkColumn` (also it can be used in the `TemplateColumn` using `{% url "admin:cmdb_device_chang" record.id %}`).